# Can I search for a job in Dubai while on a visitor's visa?

Tags: uae

Can I use a long-term single-entry visitors visa to look for work in Dubai?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? A working visa is certainly no tourist visa.

Comment: When you posted this as an answer to another question, I asked you to clarify what you meant by "work in Dubai". Do you think I did that because I enjoy typing?

Comment: Your question title and body do not match. The body only asks about one visa, whereas the title asks specifically about two visas. Could you clarify, please? (Also, as a suggestion, your name is irrelevant in the title.)

Comment: OP, I'm going to drastically edit your question...please revert the changes if I have misunderstood what you want to do.

Comment: @mkennedy great edit in the spirit of [A friendly reminder that one can EDIT as well as close a question.](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3901/32134), big kudos from me! I retracted my close vote.

Comment: Yes, this Q is for Expatriates. It has no connection to "travel".

Comment: @mkennedy You guys have done good work at editing. Hardly anything of OPs original wording remains. When I first read the question, I had no idea what it was about. But it looks like the current wording may actually be true to OPs intentions. Hard to be totally sure, though.

Answer (score 6):

I have googled for clarification of what activities are covered by a long-term visa without success. The signs are that Dubai may not care much what 'type' of activity one gets up to once allowed into the country. I have a suspicion, whether or not strictly illegal, they will be happy to turn a 'blind eye' almost all the time – but might come down with draconian repercussions at any moment that suited, whether or not 'strictly' legal. In effect, the law is what happens to be convenient at the time.

However there is precedent from other countries where job hunting is considered covered by "tourism", so there is no real risk in my opinion. And there is evidence that others have looked for jobs while in the country as a 'Tourist', for example a post by Fida Karim from [Jan 28, 2015](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/tips-job-hunting-uae-hunting-prog-proj-mgn-t-m-e-qc-research) opens with:

> Most of us, if not all go to the UAE on a visit or tourist visa for Job Hunting!

For anybody thinking of job hunting in Dubai on this basis I suggest that whole post is worth reading.